# Getting empty array as aggregate result with $unwind

Tags: node.js, mongodb, mongoose

I have a document like below, applied an aggregate query using mongoose which is pasted after json data. Here I am trying to use fields of sub collection- timing. Query results an empty array, please help to find mistake in query. Query works on removing `$unwind` and related `$project` field

```js
{  
   "_id":"5b9cbeff67ea7bc00c9917a5",
   "route_index":0,
   "route_name":"NH85", 
   "access_type":"public",
   "type":"bus", 
   "duration_days":null,
   "duration_hours":0.23,
   "created_on":"2018-09-15T07:50:17.211Z",
   "title":"Rx100",
   "description":"Ls",
   "timings":[  
      {  
         "departure":"08:00",
         "destination":"08:23",
         "_id":"5b9cbeff67ea7bc00c9917a3",
         "trackings":[  

         ]
      },
      {  
         "departure":"10:00",
         "destination":"10:23",
         "_id":"5b9cbeff67ea7bc00c9917a2",
         "trackings":[  

         ]
      }
   ],
   "created_uid":"5b8f1a9db83bc9bf3d89dcc5", 
   "__v":0
}
```

Query which I have tried is here:

```js
Transport.aggregate([
        { $unwind: "$timings" } 
        {
            $project: {
                title: 1,  
                "trip_timings": "$timings"
            }
        }, 
        { $skip: ((perPage * page) - perPage) },
        { $limit: perPage }
    ], function (err, data) {
        if (err) {
            res.json(err);
        }
        res.json(data);
    });
```

Comment: Could you post sample collection for timings as well

Comment: Try removing the $skip and $limit. May be they are just skipping the result.

Comment: Anthony, timings is a subcollection of json which i shared, you can see it in that.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try setting preserveNullAndEmptyArrays to true in the $unwind operation. It might be that the results are being skipped because the "trip_timings" field contains empty arrays. The default behaviour of $unwind is to ignore documents where the field to be unwound does not exist or is an empty array. More details here: https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/unwind/#behaviors