# Convert string time to date in mongodb

Tags: node.js, mongodb, mongoose, aggregation-framework

I have an aggregate query in which i am splitting a field value and trying to create a date using `$dateFromParts` from values in split array, unfortunately i am getting below error. Since I am using M0 instances of Mongo Altas for development purpose and its version is 3.6, i cannot use $convert and $toInt features of v4. Please suggest a solution.

**'hour' must evaluate to an integer, found string with value**

```js
{
      {  
            $addFields: {
                departure_time: { $split: ["$timings.departure", ":"] }  
            }
        }
        ,
        {
            $project: { 
                departure_date: { $dateFromParts: { 'year': dt.getUTCFullYear(), 'month': dt.getUTCMonth(), 'day': dt.getUTCDate(), 'hour': { $arrayElemAt: ["$departure_time", 0] }, 'minute': { $arrayElemAt: ["$departure_time", 1] } } }
            }
        }
}
```

Comment: could you show how sample document for the `departure_time`

Comment: Anthony, I have same document pasted in below link, timings is a $unwind-ed sub collection and departure_time is a split array of departure field in that.
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52344083/getting-empty-array-as-aggregate-result-with-lookup-and-unwind

Answer (score 1):

You can try using [**`$dateFromString`**](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/dateFromString/) in mongodb **3.6**

```
db.collection.aggregate([
  { "$project": {
    "departure_date": {
      "$dateFromString": {
        "dateString": { "$concat": ["2018-09-19", "T", "$timings.departure"] }
      }
    }
  }}
])
```